# What am I missing in rendering JSON object - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

In this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m10BZ6Q7wY5ZDYK2CuTQ?p=preview) why am I not able to access

```
{{ cartItem.selectedSeller.registered_name }}
```

Code

```
<div ng-repeat="cartItem in cartItems track by $index">
  {{ cartItem.selectedSeller }} // I can access this

  <h2> Registered Seller Name:</h2>
  {{ cartItem.selectedSeller.registered_name }} // but not this
  ===============================
</div>
```

from what I know we put `[]` in case of an array else we can access object attributes using `.` . I am surely missing some tiny logic here. I want to show Seller name for each cart products.

Comment: All the information required to understand/answer a question should be included directly in the question body -- it can't depend on an external link if possible.

Comment: what do you want to display in the view?

Comment: The `json` looks invalid and also try run inner loop to get the object values as Object itself contains another object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json has an invalid format. Try check it [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
"selectedSeller":"{\"registered_name\": \"6bc0317c-0b8b-4b39-96d4-c3377e64acfd_seller\", \"rating\": 1, \"id\": 64, \"delivers_to\": \"[{\\\"city_name\\\": \\\"Pune\\\", \\\"country\\\": \\\"India\\\", \\\"pin_code\\\": \\\"411057\\\"},{\\\"city_name\\\": \\\"Kolkata\\\", \\\"country\\\": \\\"India\\\", \\\"pin_code\\\": \\\"411058\\\"},{\\\"city_name\\\": \\\"Delhi\\\", \\\"cou
```

by the key `selectedSeller` you access string but not a object, where presented `register_name` property

Also, it is a good idea to use `json` filter, but it depends what version angular you are using.

```
{{ foo | json }}
```

Here I can see an advise about parse json, it resolve your problem, also, but I am not recommend for you that way, keep a json backend data in a consistent format and not remap it on the client side through the parsers or some custom methods.

Comment: True.Json was invalid. Corrected JSON and its working  http://plnkr.co/edit/1BOwsXhRCaDBw3gafV4R?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

cartItem.selectedSeller is a string, simply parse the string as a JSON like so in your controller:

```
$scope.cartItems = [];
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json'
  }).success(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(a){
      a.selectedSeller = JSON.parse(a.selectedSeller);
      $scope.cartItems.push(a);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply but I don't want to put extra efforts on client side  :) .